# How To, on rolling up my own character

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, roll20

I connected with a Dungeons and Dragons DM online.  He let me know he's got a campaign they play once a week.  I haven't played since the early 90's.  The whole online thing is a surprise.

The character I played with then was a Chaotic Neutral Thief, weapon of Caltrops.

The DM said I could join his campaign in Roll20.  He said I could roll my own Level 3 5e character if I wanted.  How do I go about doing this myself?  He later gave an option to join the board, read the history and go from there.  I'd like to be a self-starter.

Can anyone advise how I can take my character and roll for Level 3 5e?  (can I assume 5e means they are using that version of DnD?)

Comment: Are you asking us for help in rolling up a character in 5th edition D&D? Because that information is already covered in the Sourcebooks for the 5th edition.

Comment: That helps. Let's assume I don't have that literature.

Comment: That literature is copyrighted so we can't simply reproduce it for you. Even just paraphrasing the relevant rules would be both (1) way too long for an answer on this site, and (2) of questionable legality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, 5e means fifth edition, which is the most current release.**

1. To participate in a Roll20 campaign (our DM runs one on that tool,
   it is quite good) you have to go to the Roll20 web site and create
   an account.  You then join the game that your DM provides to you.
2. If you are going to play DnD 5e, I strongly suggest that you
   purchase The Players Handbook, as it provides all of the options for
   your Rogue/Thief.  I came back to DnD thanks to 5e, and I found it a
   well produced volume, with all of the info you need to start
   playing.
3. A less full but very handy starting package for a basic Rogue/Thief
   is in the Basic Rules, which is available for free from Wizards of
   the Coast in .pdf format.  Our campaign began with three of us using
   only the Basic Rules to create our characters and begin play.  It
   worked out fine, but I did then buy the PHB.
4. Create the character, then level him up to third one level at a
   time, taking note of the new powers and skills.  You need to choose
   an archetype at third level.  All that is available in the Basic
   Rules is Thief.  Arcane Trickster and Assassin are in the PHB.  Work
   with your DM on making that decision as it shapes how your character will play.

[Wizards of the Coast official web site.](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules)
Choose the "printer friendly" option.  It will guide you through the character creation process.

Comment: Very nice.  Good tips to start out.  Thank you.

Comment: If this answered your question, you can click on the check box in the left margin to accept it, or, you can wait for another answer that may be better.  Welcome, and best wishes!